# Maintain different device versions in code

Tags: c#, .net

I wrote an application (C#, .NET 2.0) which is used to control electronic device connected via serialport.

Now device software has been updated with some new functions which are not avaible in older version.

How can I maintain these changes in code so that new app version will support both device versions?

I know i can use some if statement or preprocessor commands to check device version, but what is the correct way to do this in C#?

EDIT:

I think I should write more about my problem. Assume that i have a class used to convert some values from older device version:

```
class Conversions
{ 
 public static float IntToPressure(int parameter)
 {
  return AlgorithmA(parameter);
 }
 public static float IntToUnderpressure(int parameter);
 {
  return AlgorithmB(parameter);
 }
}
```

In new version I need only one method: IntToPressure which will convert all pressure parameters, + new method for temperature:

```
class Conversions
{ 
 public static float IntToPressure(int parameter)
 {
  //changed
  return NewAlgorithm(parameter);
 }
 //new
 public static float IntToTemperature(int parameter)
 {
  return TempAlgorithm(parameter);
 }
}
```

The same is with classes that uses Conversions (old version):

```
class UsingConversions
{ 
 public float GetPressure()
 {
  return Conversions.IntToPressure(this.somePressureParameter);
 }
 public float GetUnderpressure()
 {
  return Conversions.IntToUnderpressure(this.someUnderpressureParameter);
 }
}
```

New class version looks like (+new funcionality):

```
class UsingConversions
{ 
 public float GetPressure()
 {
  return Conversions.IntToPressure(this.somePressureParameter);
 }
 public float GetUnderpressure()
 {
  //changed
  return Conversions.IntToPressure(this.someUnderpressureParameter);
 }
 //new
 public float GetTemperature()
 {
  return Conversions.IntToTemperature(this.someTemperatureParameter);
 }
}
```

Another problem is that new app version contains definitions of new classes used to configure device and for using new device functions.

Answer (score 0):

You could factor out the difference between the devices in two subclasses and instantiate the correct one by checking which device is plugged. This won't work if you need to export those changes to the outside world